# Is there a way to zoom in Texmaker like in TeXworks?

Tags: texmaker

I've recently discovered Texmaker and prefer it vastly to TeXworks.  But one thing that I liked about TeXworks is that I could click on my compiled pdf and it would zoom in closely enough to examine my text for small formatting errors.  Is there a way to do this in Texmaker?

Answer (score 4):

No, the internal PDF viewer in Texmaker does not, as far as I can see, have such a magnifying glass. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + scroll, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to zoom in/out, but that is as close as you get.

There is an open feature request for this:

- https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=1105